# preg_match_all not finding all occurences

Tags: preg-match-all

I have an issue using preg_match_all on nmap port scan results.
I would like to check if port 80 and 443 are open.

For instance if I do this :

`preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,5}\/[a-z]{3} open/', $result, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

I only have a result for 443/tcp open. 80/tcp open doesn't show up. The resultat from nmap looks like this :

Not shown: 998 filtered ports PORT STATE SERVICE 80/tcp open http 443/tcp open https Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.85 seconds

I did a rtrim before the preg_match to be sure there was no hidden character in the way.

And when I type this :

`preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,5}\/[a-z]{3}/', $result, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

I do have both ports showing up in results.
I must say I don't understand why it would find 443 but not 80 while the two are written in the same way.

If you have any clue.

Thank you :)

Comment: [As this demo shows](https://rextester.com/PQOF93275), your first call to `preg_match_all` is already working as expected.  What is the exact problem here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why but this doesn't work on my end, I do a print_r on the global $out variable and it only returns this : Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 443/tcp open ) ). I'm using php 8, maybe it's the reason ? I don't know I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry for double posting. Maybe it has something to see with the way I received the nmap result. I do a rtrim(file_get_content(myserverscript.php)) because the script is on distant server. So maybe the way it is formatting results ?

Comment: I suspect the space between "80/tcp" and "open" to not be a simple space but a non-breakable space (or any other blank character). Try to replace this space with `\s` and use the u modifier: `~[0-9]{1,5}/tcp\s+open~u`

Comment: Note that `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is the flag by default, it is not mandatory to put it.